# i keep getting TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given when i use the custom bot command i made in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a minigame bot for my friend's discord server and one of the commands is deathcount() which basically is supposed to return the points the person has by using the user/person who called the commands id to get the no. of points he has in the python dictionary(i know it's kinda dumb to use this but i might change it to sqlite or just a csv file later) but when i call the command using !deathcount in the server it returns the error **TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**, the full error it gives is **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given**

here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
keys=dict() 

@client.command()
async def deathcount(ctx):
  ide=ctx.author.id
  if ide in keys:
      ctx.send("your balance is:",keys[ide])
  else:
      ctx.send("please make a account")
```

Comment: Try To Concatenate "Your Balance Is:" with keys[ide] like this ctx.send(  "your balance is:"+keys[ide]  )

Answer (score 0):

send():

```py
class Massageable:
    ...

    async def send(message, ...):...
    #              ^^^^^^^
```

try it:

```py
ctx.send(f"your balance is: {keys[ide]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `ctx.send` is:

```
ctx.send(self, msg):
```

where self is provided automatically and msg is a string that you pass as a parameter.

To solve your problem you can concatenate the 2 parameters of your `send`

```
ctx.send("your balance is:"+keys[ide])
```

or

```
ctx.send("your balance is:"+str(keys[ide]))
```

depending on whether keys stores numbers or strings.